# What is the JSON schema to create Dialog flow CX agent via binary import?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents/restore

Where can I get more information regarding the schema of input file and how do I parse .blob file received from exporting some agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: It is not possible to create a readable JSON from the .blob file and this behavior is intended.

This is because there might be users that will create an agent from JSON only. Doing this might bypass all the design time check and validation and will result in a lot of internal errors in Dialogflow.

As a workaround if you want to check something (ex. Flow, Intents) in JSON format you can send a request on the following endpoints to get these:

1. Agent resources:

   - Call [ListIntents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.intents/list), [ListEntityTypes](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.entityTypes/list), [ListWebhooks](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.webhooks/list), [ListFlows](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.flows/list)
2. Flow resources:

   - Call [ListPages](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.flows.pages/list), [ListTransitionRouteGroups](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.flows.transitionRouteGroups/list)